# Excel Plugin for SMS Sending website

Tags: c#, plugins

I want to develop a SMS Excel plugin. I want to use language c#. Which version of visual studio supports windows 7 ultimate? can anyone please suggests me, how to develop this? I also take help from microsoft's website. which type of project shoul i choose for this? win32 or console etc. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Excel add-in project. Under the office add-in section. I would not take a version of visual studio older than the version of excel you are writing it for.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx